# The most accessible markup for a multi-state toggle

Tags: html, accessibility, markup

I'm working on a toggle that has more than just an on/off state, like this one:

[image: Multi-state toggle]

It has three different states, where only one is active at a time (like radio buttons). NOTE: My question is not about the best design for theme switcher, but about the most accessible markup for this type of multi state toggle in generel.

So I'm thinking markup could be either:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>View in:</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="light" name="theme" value="light" checked>
  <label for="light">Light theme</label>
  <input type="radio" id="dark" name="theme" value="dark">
  <label for="light">Dark theme</label>
  <input type="radio" id="contrast" name="theme" value="constrast">
  <label for="light">High contrast</label>
</fieldset>
```

Or it could be:

```
<div class="toggle-thingy">
  <label>View in:</label>
  <button aria-pressed="true">Light theme</button>
  <button aria-pressed="false">Dark theme</button>
  <button aria-pressed="false">High contrast</button>
</div>
```

Naturally it kind of feels like radio buttons, because it is supposed to work exactly like radio buttons. But the reason I'm considering the latter option above is that e.g. https://inclusive-components.design/toggle-button/ is opposing the use of `<input type="checkbox">` for a general purpose toggle button (as it is not about submitting data for a form), and suggest using a button with the aria-pressed attribute instead. So I'm thinking you could use the same argument for a radio button-thingy, that is not really about submitting form data? But also going with the aria-pressed solution above, there is really nothing for connecting the three buttons, like the name attribute for radio buttons.

So, any suggestions other ideas for the best and most accessible markup etc.?

Answer (score 2):

In general I would say that relying on native HTML elements and attributes is the safer bet, instead of relying on ARIA.

For this concrete case, I checked [screen reader support for `aria-pressed`](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-pressed_attribute). According to these tests, there still seem to be issues in conveying the change of the pressed state in NVDA and VoiceOver.

Additionally, changing option in a radio button group is possible by means of arrow keys. It’s a faster interaction.

This might even be expected by users from a horizontal group of buttons as well, which resembles a `toolbar`. Even more so if the transition is a sliding block.

**Based on this, I would recommend radio buttons.**

If you stick to the Toggle buttons, you should fix the label.

The `<label>` is misused in the second button group example. It needs to be associated to a control. In this case, a `group` role would be required which provides the label, just as it’s done in the other example by means of a `<fieldset>`.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>View in:</legend>
  <button aria-pressed="true">Light theme</button>
  <button aria-pressed="false">Dark theme</button>
  <button aria-pressed="false">High contrast</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, think I'll go with radio buttons then.